# I want to display the marquee continuosly so that start and end should be continuosly

Tags: html, marquee

I am using below code. But I am getting start and end, I am finding white space. It should be without any start and end gap. It should be continuously.

I am using this code:

```
<MARQUEE direction="right" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=50>
    Welcome to the Website. Welcome to the demo.Welcome to the Website. Welcome to the demo.
</MARQUEE>
```

It is going to right and then start. So gap is there. I want to display continuously. So, with naked eye, we should be not able to find start and end of marquee

Please help me with this

Comment: The `<marquee>` element is obsolete and should no longer be used

Comment: But either way, [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee).

Comment: In fact, the `<marquee>` element has never been part of any HTML spec ever.

Comment: ALL-CAPS ELEMENTS? Now that's what I call old school.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/crawler/index.htm

I have edited as per your need in the following code, save as .html and put the downloaded .js file in the same folder as html file is saved.
you will have to download .js file from the link given.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="crawler.js">

/* Text and/or Image Crawler Script v1.53 (c)2009-2011 John Davenport Scheuer
as first seen in http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/
username: jscheuer1 - This Notice Must Remain for Legal Use
*/

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee" id="mycrawler">
Welcome to the Website. Welcome to the demo.Welcome to the Website. Welcome tothe demo.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
marqueeInit({
uniqueid: 'mycrawler',
style: {
    'padding': '5px',
    'width': '450px',

    //'border': '0px solid #CC3300'
},
inc: 5, //speed - pixel increment for each iteration of this marquee's movement
mouse: 'cursor driven', //mouseover behavior ('pause' 'cursor driven' or false)
moveatleast: 2,
neutral: 150,
persist: true,
savedirection: true
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```